# Executar ALTER em uma PROCEDURE que é referenciada por outro objeto

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou tentando alterar/*dropar* a funcao `[xxxx]` conforme o código.

Porém me retorna o seguinte erro

```
Msg 3729, Level 16, State 3, Procedure xxxxx, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 15] 
Cannot ALTER 'dbo.xxxxx' because it is being referenced by object 'bbbbb'
```

Pelas minhas buscas vi que não há como realizar um comando DDL para funções escalares com a clausula 'SCHEMABINDING', outro ponto é que a tabela em que o SELECT da function consulta não há uma constraint.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[xxxxx]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Cliente as nvarchar(100) 
)
RETURNS bigint
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN (0)

END
GO
```

**OBS:** Sim, quero que ela retorne 0.

Gostaria de saber se é possivel realizar esse `DROP/ALTER`

Comment: O `SCHEMABINDING` não olha apenas às `CONSTRAINTS` das tabelas que consulta, mas também aos tipos, ou seja, utilizando isso a função fica referenciada à tabela para evitar que a mesma mude. Precisa mesmo de utilizar isso?

Comment: Quem é ou o que é 'bbbbb'?